# Restart delegate method after certain condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

In this [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html), OpenCV has defined a delegate method in `cap_ios.h` for video processing. The declaration is like:

```
@class CvVideoCamera;

@protocol CvVideoCameraDelegate <NSObject>

#ifdef __cplusplus
// delegate method for processing image frames
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image;
#endif

@end
```

And, I put my code for video processing inside function `(void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image;` in `ViewController.mm`.

When processing video frames in *OpenCV + C++*, I use `do-while` loop to process every frame captured by camera. In the loop, the code won't continue but restart from the beginning if some condition is true. The code is like:

```
do {
    captureAndDoSomething();

    if (condition) {
        continue;     // To capture a new frame
    }

    doSomething();
} while(...);
```

So, my question is how to restart function `(void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image` in iOS coding? There is no loop now and I cannot use `continue` any more.

```
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image {
    doSomething();    // Capturing is done by delegate I think

    if (condition) {
                      // How to restart and capture a new frame now?
    }     

    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Post a notification after completion of that function, so that you get notified to call the function again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where I am wrong and  used `goto` to resolve my issue. Actually it is not about delegate method.

[One thing to beware](http://blog.kmaku.com/?p=20):

> When you use goto keyword in your code. You must be sure that any
>   variable should not be declared below goto keyword and above the label
>   it points within its scope.

Otherwise, you will get `goto into protected scope` error. For my case, the code should be:

```
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image {
    doSomething();    
    initialize();         // Method 1: variables declared before goto

    if (condition) {
        goto fin;
    }     

    doSomething();
    if (1) {
        initialize()      // Method 2: variables declared in its scope
    }

fin:
    lastAction();
}
```

Both **Method 1** and **Method 2** works.